# How to get text from edit text in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

Okay..  I have 2 classes :-
1. `Apple.class`
2. `Banana.class`

And 2 .XML file:-
1. `ear.xml`
2. `nose.xml`

Now, I want to add a edit text box in `apple.class`
But I want to print that text that user input in `banana.class`

Comment: Try Google first, then come back to StackOverflow.

Comment: before google i think you need a good android book

Comment: Yeah you are guys are....   I m noob...   But tell me how can I master in android

Answer (score 2):

1) Get the entered value from edittext by the following

```
String content = EditText.getText().toString();
```

2) Then pass the string "content" to the next Activity using Intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Apple.this,Banana.class);
i.putstring("EditTextValue",content);
startactivity(i);
```

3) Get the data in Banana class and set to a textview.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code when clicked on the button , send data from AppleActivity to BananaActivty  :

```
String value = edittext.getText().toString().trim(); //get text from editText
Intent i=new Intent(FirstDemo.this,SecondDemo.class);
i.putExtra("key", value);//you can add other key value
startActivity(i);
```

then in other class you have to get value from Intent like below:

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key"));
```

Hope to be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

```
//one activity(FirstDemo)

EditText ed1,ed2;

String st="",st2="";

//onCreate method:-

st=ed1.getText().toString().trim();
 st2=ed2.getText().toString().trim();

//then click on button

Intent i=new Intent(FirstDemo.this,SecondDemo.class);
i.putExtra("id", st);
i.putExtra("u_email", st2);
startActivity(i);

//then next Activity(SecondDemo):-
Edittext e1,e2;

 Intent j = getIntent();
 e1.setText(j.getStringExtra("id"));
e2.setText(j.getStringExtra("u_email"));
```